Write headers for a kafka topic
I have this toy FlinkSql app with a kafka topic in input, and want to output into another kafka topic.
(I'm using the upsert-kafka connector for reasons.)
I would like to update/create the headers for the output messages (Ideally based on the input headers)... but I cannot make it work!
From what I can tell:

I am able read the headers of the input messages
but they are inserted as part of the output message value!

Details:
input
I have an input table that looks like this:
CREATE TABLE my_input (
    id      STRING,
    headers MAP<STRING, BYTES> METADATA,
    PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
    'connector'.   = 'upsert-kafka',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '...',
    'topic'        = 'my_input',
    'key.format'   = 'raw',
    'value.format' = 'avro-confluent', 
    'value.avro-confluent.url' = '...',
    'value.avro-confluent.basic-auth.credentials-source' = 'USER_INFO',
    'value.avro-confluent.basic-auth.user-info' = '...'
)

output
I have an output table that looks the same:
CREATE TABLE my_output (
    key     STRING,
    headers MAP<STRING, STRING> METADATA,   -- Also tried MAP<String, Bytes>
    PRIMARY KEY (key) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
    'connector'    = 'upsert-kafka',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '...',
    'topic'        = 'my_output',
    'key.format'   = 'raw',
    'value.format' = 'avro-confluent', 
    'value.avro-confluent.url' = '...',
    'value.avro-confluent.basic-auth.credentials-source' = 'USER_INFO',
    'value.avro-confluent.basic-auth.user-info' = '...'
)

and my FlinkSQL looks like this:
statement
INSERT INTO my_output
SELECT
  'hello' as name,
  my_input.id as key,
  MAP['some_key', 'some_value'] as `headers`
FROM my_input

When consuming the messages on the output topic, I can see that the headers are empty, and that the headers column became part of the message value, rather than the message headers!
{
  key: 'key1',
  headers: {},  <--- this is empty!
  value: {
    name: 'hello',
    headers: [{some_key: 'some_value'}]
  }
}

What am I missing ??

Note: I completely misunderstood the question so I've rewritten my answer. I'm not sure what's wrong with your code tbh. It looks mostly correct.
Here is what I have been using to test and verify that the results indeed go into a header. The type indeed needs to be MAP<String, Bytes>.
CREATE TABLE kafka (
  `physical_1` STRING,
  `physical_2` INT,
  `timestamp-type` STRING METADATA VIRTUAL,
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA,
  `leader-epoch` INT METADATA VIRTUAL,
  headers MAP<STRING, BYTES> METADATA,
  `partition` INT METADATA VIRTUAL,
  `topic` STRING METADATA VIRTUAL,
  `physical_3` BOOLEAN,   PRIMARY KEY (physical_2) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
  'topic' = 'test',
  'key.format'   = 'json',
  'value.format' = 'json',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'PLAINTEXT://localhost:54152',
  'properties.group.id' = 'flink-tests'
)

INSERT INTO kafka
VALUES
 ('data 1', 1, TIMESTAMP '2020-03-08 13:12:11.123', MAP['k1', X'C0FFEE', 'k2', X'BABE01'], TRUE),
 ('data 2', 2, TIMESTAMP '2020-03-09 13:12:11.123', CAST(NULL AS MAP<STRING, BYTES>), FALSE),
 ('data 3', 3, TIMESTAMP '2020-03-10 13:12:11.123', MAP['k1', X'102030', 'k2', X'203040'], TRUE)

Can you try out this example and see if it works for you. If not please try upgrading Flink or give me a specific version to test against.

I'm not sure I understand: I don't want to change the key! I just want to have headers... Does it mean that with avro-confluent as a format for the key, the headers will be magically populated ?

I have rewritten my response. I misunderstood your question.
